# Override archive-product.php for a specific woocommerce product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to override archive-product.php for a single category.
In my case, i have 6 categories to which archive-product.php is applied .
but i want to override a category named " new "  for a reason .
How could it be possible ? please let me know .

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're asking how to apply a different archive template to a specific product category's archive.

According to [WooCommerce core code](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-template-loader.php#L61), you can simply name a template as `taxonomy-product_cat-new.php` and it should be used as the "new" product category's archive.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work . i solved it another way with this code :                                                                                                           $cat = get_query_var('product_cat');

if(isset($cat) && $cat=='new-products')
{
 
}
else
{ }       where i get category in archive-product.php and then applied my design in if part of the statement  otherwise else part will work for other categories .

Comment: I just tested it and confirmed that this template (needs to be in your theme) does indeed get called for a specific product category... which was my best guess for what you were asking, since your question was pretty vague. It does depend on what you put in the template as obviously if this new template only calls `wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );` (as the category and tag templates do) then it won't look any different from the `archive-product.php` template.